# Issue upgrading Rails 2.3 to 3.2.11 - undefined method `normalize_parameters' for class `ActionController::Request' (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using the [rails_upgrade](https://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade) plugin I successfully upgraded a 2.3 app to 3.0.6. My goal is to upgrade that 2.3 app to 3.2.11. Using the same process I'm able to get pretty far but I'm stuck on this one Active Support error. Any help would be appreciated -

```
/Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:31:in `alias_method': undefined method `normalize_parameters' for class `ActionController::Request' (NameError)
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:31:in `alias_method_chain'
from /Users/TravisKs/Sites/rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/config/initializers/patch_for_1.9.2.rb:37:in `<class:Request>'
from /Users/TravisKs/Sites/rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/config/initializers/patch_for_1.9.2.rb:31:in `<module:ActionController>'
from /Users/TravisKs/Sites/rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/config/initializers/patch_for_1.9.2.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /Users/TravisKs/Sites/rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/TravisKs/Sites/rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/config.ru:3:in `require'
from /Users/TravisKs/Sites/rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
from /Users/TravisKs/Sites/rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/config.ru:in `new'
from /Users/TravisKs/Sites/rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/config.ru:in `<main>'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /Users/TravisKs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing rabbitsferritsandgerbils.com/config/initializers/patch_for_1.9.2.rb seems to solve the problem for me.  I did have to switch over to ruby 1.9.3.